# how to call multiple files on form submit

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

i have form in which i want three functionality among two is working. First one is when form gets submit fetch data from db and display on form_process.php file and second is store form data in db on submit, this two is working fine in form_process.php. Now i want to send all form data via email so i want to do process in email_process.php. So how should i call email_process.php ?

i am already using form action for form_process.php

```
<form class="cost_calculation" action="form_process.php" name="cost_estimation" id="cost_estimation" method="post">
```

submit button:

```
  <div class="get_quote_btn">
    <input  class="get_quote" name="submit" id="getquote" type="submit" value="Get Quote" />
    </div>
```

I tried using ajax but it's not working

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
     $("input").click(function(){
     $.ajax({url: "email_process.php", success: function(result){
    $("#cost_estimation").html(result);
}});
});
});
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to create functions and call that functions one by one after success response or simply include files one by one so your code can run after you hit submit button

Comment: Is there any alternate way?

Comment: There is no alternate way of doing this or you can call ajax one by one after getting response.

Comment: _“So how should i call email_process.php ?”_ - include it, in the same place where you do the rest of the form data processing …?

Comment: @CBroe after data save in database included file will hit and code start processing if no syntax error. Also you can get POST request in that file too.

Comment: You can use functions to handle each of those processes, let the first function call the next function on successful execution and so on.

Comment: i also tried onsubmit="doubleSubmit(this)" but that is also not working

Comment: just make a function in `email_process.php` that does the email sending and `include 'here'` it in `form_process.php`, then just like you normally do, use the function in there, after everything is done, redirect it to where you need it to be, thank you page, or something

Comment: @Kevin let me try this i will let you know if it works

Comment: This method didn't worked it shows 500 error